# Find the matrix of linear transformation $L(p)(x)=(1+4x)p(x)+(x-x^2)p'(x)-(x^2+x^3)p''(x)$ with respect to basis $\mathcal{B}=\{3,x-1,x^2+1\}$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Find the matrix of linear transformation $L(p)(x)=(1+4x)p(x)+(x-x^2)p'(x)-(x^2+x^3)p''(x)$ with respect to standard basis $\mathcal{B_1}=\{1,x,x^2\}$ and with basis $\mathcal{B}=\{3,x-1,x^2+1\}$ where $p(x)\in\mathbb{R_2}[x]$.

In standard basis $\Rightarrow p(x)=a+bx+cx^2\Rightarrow$
$$L(p)(x)=a+(4a+2b)x+(3b+c)x^2$$

$$L(1)=0x^2+4x+1$$
$$L(x)=3x^2+2x+0$$
$$L(x^2)=x^2+0x+0\Rightarrow [L]_{\mathcal{B_1}}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 3 & 1 \\
        4 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

**Question**: How to construct matrix of $L$ in the new basis directly from standard basis?

If standard basis is not used, $\Rightarrow p(x)=3a+b(x-1)+c(x^2+1)\Rightarrow$

$$L(p)(x)=(1+4x)(3a+b(x-1)+c(x^2+1))+(x-x^2)(b+2cx)-(x^2+x^3)2c$$

$$L(3)=3\alpha+(x-1)\beta+(x^2+1)\gamma=3+12x\Rightarrow \alpha=2,\beta=3,\gamma=0\Rightarrow$$ $$L(3)=3\cdot 2+(x-1)\cdot 3+(x^2+1)\cdot 0$$

$$L(x-1)=3\alpha+(x-1)\beta+(x^2+1)\gamma=3x^2-2x+1\Rightarrow \alpha=\frac{4}{3},\beta=-2,\gamma=3\Rightarrow$$
$$L(x-1)=3\cdot \frac{4}{3}+(x-1)\cdot (-2)+(x^2+1)\cdot 3$$

$$L(x^2+1)=3\alpha+(x-1)\beta+(x^2+1)\gamma=x^2+4x+1\Rightarrow \alpha=\frac{4}{3},\beta=4,\gamma=1\Rightarrow$$
$$L(x^2+1)=3\cdot \frac{4}{3}+(x-1)\cdot 4+(x^2+1)\cdot 1\Rightarrow$$
$$[L]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 4/3 & 4/3 \\
        3 & -2 & 4 \\
        0 & 3 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

**Question**: Is the matrix in basis $\mathcal{B}=\{3,x-1,x^2+1\}$ correct?

Comment: Do you think $L(3)=3+12x$ and $L(3)=3\cdot 2+(x-1)\cdot 3+(x^2+1)\cdot 0$ are compatible?

Comment: @Did That is what confuses me here. How to form column vectors in new basis for $L(3),L(x-1),L(x^2+1)$?

Comment: Surely one step is to write $L(3)=3+12x$ in the basis $\mathcal B$ **correctly**, and surely you can do that, no?

Comment: @Did Is this right: $3+12x=5\cdot 3+12(x-1)+0(x^2+1)$?

Comment: Now to $L(x-1)$ and $L(x^2+1)$... If I were you, I would check thoroughly the computations in the post.